# How to make crouch/uncrouch smooth?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the crouching/standing-up smoother and slower, as currently crouching/uncrouching is so quick(I mean transition between crouching/uncrouching)

```
 private void Start()
    {
        startYScale = transform.localScale.y;
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }
     private void PlayerMovement() 
        {
            currentSpeed = moveSpeed;
            move = controls.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
            movement = (move.y * transform.forward) + (move.x * transform.right);
            if (isRunning)
            {
                //run = controls.Player.Run.ReadValue<float>();
                currentSpeed = runSpeed; 
                Vector3 running = (move.y * transform.forward) + (move.x * transform.right);
                controller.Move(running * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (crouching)
             {
                currentSpeed = crouchSpeed;
                isRunning = false; 
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, crouchYScale, transform.localScale.z);
               // controller.radius = 0.2f; 
                      
            }
            else
            {
                currentSpeed = moveSpeed;
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, startYScale, transform.localScale.z);
            }
           
            controller.Move(movement * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
```

How would I fix that? is there a way to make the transition slower and smoother? please help.

**Edit**:
I tried changing the position of the camera too when crouching to make the transition from standing up to crouching smoother.

```
   private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            var desierdHeight = crouching ? crouchYScale : startYScale;
            if (controller.height != desierdHeight)
            {
                AdjustHeight(desierdHeight);
                /* var camPos = playerCamera.transform.position;
                 camPos.y = controller.height;
                 playerCamera.transform.position = camPos;*/
               playerCamera.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,controller.height, 0); 
            }
        }
 private void AdjustHeight(float height)
    {
        float center = height / 2; 
        controller.height = Mathf.Lerp(controller.height, height, crouchSpeed);
        controller.center = Vector3.Lerp(controller.center, new Vector3(0, center,0), crouchSpeed);
    }
```

but the transition is still fast.

Comment: you mean the transition is quick?

Comment: yes, this is what I mean